# Attaching Files to Emails

Tags: powershell

I have written the following in Powershell to try and send an email with an attachment.

```
$FileDate = Get-Date
$SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
$SmtpUser = 'blah@blah.com'
$smtpPassword = 'blah'
$MailtTo = 'blah@blah.com'
$MailFrom = 'blah@blah.com'
$MailSubject = "The file for $FileDate is attached."
$MailBody = "Please take action"
$attachment= "C:\Users\my user\myfile.txt"
$attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment ($attachment)  
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -
ArgumentList $SmtpUser, $($smtpPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -
AsPlainText -Force)

Send-MailMessage -To "$MailtTo" -from "$MailFrom"  -Subject $MailSubject -
Body $MailBody -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials -
attachments "$attach"
```

When I execute it, I get the following error in Powershell

```
Send-MailMessage : Could not find file 
'C:\Users\myuser\System.Net.Mail.Attachment'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To "$MailtTo" -from "$MailFrom"  -Subject $MailSubject -
Body $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MailMessage],
FileNotFoundException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

But the file is 100% there.  Can anyone help me with where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Attachments` parameter of `Send-MailMessage` expects a string input, so I don't think you need to create the `$attach` variable at all, but instead just use `$attachment` which already contains the string path of the file you want to attach:

```
.. -attachments $attachment
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that and got a different error

    Send-MailMessage : Could not find file'
    C:\Users\myuser\System.Net.Mail.Attachment'.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Send-MailMessage -To "$MailtTo" -from "$MailFrom"  -Subject 
    $MailSubject -Body $ ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MailMessage], 
    FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: Actually it looks like the `-attachments` parameter expects string input, so you should just use `$attachment` as the variable with it and do away with creating `$attach` at all.